# Clone a GitHub repository using WebStorm

Tags: github, webstorm, clone

I want to clone a repository with WebStorm. Is this possible and how to do this?

Comment: **Menu > Git > Clone**, with bundled **Git** and **GitHub** plugin enabled and no external plugin required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to connect your github account with the Webstorm and then use

> Get from VCS

Then paste the git URL which you want to clone